# Default encoding of Python 3's open() under Windows. sys.getdefaultencoding() setting not respected

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I've been pulling my hair out over this issue for several hours now.

I have a message file I want to generate using django's makemessages command, which works just fine in a Linux environment which actually handles locale settings in a sane way. However, when I try the same thing under Windows, every time python tries to open a file, it assumes it is encoded in `cp932` (SHIFT-JIS), which causes all sorts of havoc.

Manually adding `encoding='utf-8'` to every `open` call works, but that's hardly a good way of fixing the problem. Is there any way to force `open` to use a specific default encoding?

- `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns 'utf-8', for some arcane reason this setting is not respected
- PYTHONIOENCODING and PYTHONENCODING are both set to 'utf-8'
- My code page is set to `cp65001`

This is my python version string:

`Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

EDIT: I've noticed that `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns `cp932`, so I guess finding a Windows locale with `utf-8` as its default would do the trick. Does such a thing even exist?

Comment: It may be a bug in 3.3 on Windows if you really can't find a solution. On the other hand, being explicit about the encoding when calling `open()` is not a bad idea.

Comment: Well, I know that being explicit about the encoding is never a bad idea, the issue is that replacing all calls to `open` in the relevant parts of Django's utilities isn't really feasible. I've discovered that `locale.getpreferredencoding()` does return `cp932`, so that might be the issue. Are there any Windows locales that set this to `utf-8`?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not too familiar with that. But the fact that it returns `cp932` may indeed indicate that it's the locale setting on your machine (or Windows in general) that interferes here.

Comment: I should add that this problem can (in principle) be solved by overriding locale.getpreferredencoding (which I temporarily did to get past the issue), but I really hope there's an alternative way to accomplish this.

Comment: You might suggest to Django developers that they let *you*, rather than Microsoft, specify the encoding that *you* want Django to use in its internal open calls.  In the meanwhile, upgrade at least to 3.3.5 for its bugfixes; there might be some related to unicode.

Comment: Well, fortunately the Windows box is not a production system, so it's not really critical, but I'll update my python version anyway. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: There is a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303919/python-3-0-open-default-encoding). In summary, on Windows, python `open` use encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()` method.

Comment: This is also a problem when you're relying on libraries that don't specify an encoding for `open()`, such as `pygettext`. Explicitly specifying `utf-8` is not an option and it leaves you with no way to control the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: This is for python3 and it's just a way to avoid writing the encoding in all system access in a python script. For changing your windows shell encoding, try: chcp 65001