# Which "platform-dependent" encodings does `open()` default to, on major platforms?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, localization

According to the manual, the default input and output encoding of [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is "platform dependent", and [*usually*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27452317/699305) given by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. But what exactly (or approximately) are these platform-dependent defaults?

**Edit:** A useful answer might be in the form of a list of configurations (presumably a combination of OS and some language/localization settings) and the resulting default encoding.

I'm not expecting a complete reference, but I would like to know what to expect, and what factors to look into, when one of my students stumbles on code that I can run without incident (my box defaults to `utf-8`). Ideally I can say in advance "If your system is set up like X, you should do Y".

I've looked at [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d1bf37def4fd/Lib/locale.py#l506) of `getpreferredencoding()` and I can see that a number of environment variables are checked, but I don't have a menagerie of different machines to test by hand-- and I don't know what factors going into the setting of all these environment variables. My students are from a variety of nationalities (but mostly Dutch), and use PCs, Macs, and Chromebooks. Is anyone here able to offer an overview of what I can expect?

Comment: *"on code that I can run"* -- if it is a Python source code then tell your students to use the [encoding declaration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/): `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` if their source code uses non-ascii literals (utf-8 is the default in Python 3 and therefore the encoding declaration is optional there).

Comment: Nope, this is about code that reads files with `open()` without specifying an encoding, as the question says.

Comment: if you don't know the character encoding then read files using binary mode `'rb'`. Otherwise you can only guess the encoding (`chardet` module).

Comment: @JF, I know how to deal with files and their encodings. Please read the question, and don't explain the world to me. We've been coming across each other on this site for years, usually in Python questions.

Comment: The problem you describe in your question is unsolvable. Require your students to hand in any text files as UTF-8 (which you *can* verify with reasonable accuracy).

Comment: But I'm not asking how to eliminate the behavior. My question asks about a  breakdown of what default encodings are used, for the most common "platforms" (presumably OS's and national language settings, but who knows?)

Comment: @alexis On Windows I think it's the system code page [(list)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654.aspx). Given a text file in one of these encodings, it's hard to tell what codec was used. You should expect it to be *random* and [*impossible to guess*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts).

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of info I'm after. But is it always just the system codepage? (Anyway, a human can determine the encoding if they know the language of the text; that's not the problem.)

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I don't perfectly understand the problem you (were, 7 years ago) encountering. For my purposes I am just using `locale.getpreferredencoding()` for academic interest, but always specifying 'utf-8' in all my code where such an option is available. I think it would be preferable if a Python app or script or conf file could be configured with a simple switch to say "always assume utf-8". Maybe it can ...

Comment: Hi Mike, the problem was that I was dealing with code written by a lot of beginner programmers who were not programming defensively, and regularly getting different results than I did. Of course anyone can avoid surprises _in their own code_ by always being careful, but sometimes we encounter code that was written in a different environment, and possibly worked correctly for the author.

I was teaching Python, but I'd expect the same in any open programming ecosystem. So I wanted to understand what was going on, and how to analyze it beyond saying "just add `"utf-8"`, that should fix it".

Answer (score 0):

I think on Windows it would be the current *code page*, often labelled as ANSI. That's the codec you get on Windows if you specify the name `'mbcs'`.

However **for most practical purposes you should assume the text files will just have some random encoding.** I don't think it's useful to dig into the details of `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. If I'm not mistaken, you can override that default in your script anyway.

I don't know what you're going to do with those text but if you're going to get files in all those different encodings, know there [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) no [reliable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx) way of finding out that encoding.

If you want to inspect those files one by one by trial-and-error then go ahead, but I would just avoid the problem by telling the students to submit in a set encoding, eg. UTF-8. It's easy enough to open files using `open(blabla, 'w', encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: Windows uses heuristics to infer the encoding, but Python uses a "default" that is independent of file contents. I am not (and the question is not) after any sort of content-based inference.

Comment: What I'm going to do with this information is, I want to be able to say "under X conditions you can expect UTF-8 to be the encoding, but if your computer is like Y then you will get something else." Portability aside, the encoding parameter is optional so we should know when it needs to be used. It bugs me that I have to teach this stuff and don't know what my students can expect. (It was simple enough when the default was ascii-- why couldn't it become "utf8" for everyone?)

Comment: Also, I _think_ it's the system codepage too, but I'm not sure that's always the case; and as I mention in the question, it might be that not even `getpreferredencoding()` is always obeyed. So I was hoping for something based on references, or on extensive experience.

Comment: @alexis you almost always need to use the `encoding` parameter when opening a text file with non-ASCII characters. As for the default, “It's platform-dependent and you can't rely on it having a certain value” is a good enough explanation.

Comment: This boils down to "your question doesn't need answering". Even if you're right (and you might be :-)), I'd still prefer to know the answer...