# What encoding does open() use by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I tried using some code like this to read a JSON file (encoded using UTF-8):

```
input = open("json/world_bank.json")
i=0
for l in input:
    i+=1
print(i)
```

But I got a `UnicodeDecodeError`. However, it started working once I tried explicitly specifying an encoding:

```
input = open("json/world_bank.json",encoding="utf8")
```

I thought the `open` function would use `"utf8"` as the default encoding? Why does it need to be specified?

Comment: What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` return on your system?

Comment: here it is 'mbcs' @marcelm

Comment: Ah hmm, that doesn't tell me too much; could you check `open("json/world_bank.json").encoding` as well?

Answer (score 86):

The default UTF-8 encoding of Python 3 only extends to conversions between `bytes` and `str` types. `open()` instead [chooses an appropriate default encoding based on the environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns), but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the `codecs` module for the list of supported encodings.

For example, a Windows machine with a Western Europe/North America locale will normally use the 8-bit Windows-1252 character set (Python calls this encoding `'cp1252'`).

Comment: Fortunately there are [recent attempts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0597/) to end this madness... someday.

Comment: 3.9 is installed on my machine and it's still using Windows 1252 encoding. PEP 597 linked by @Jeyekomon now says Python 3.10.

Comment: @StefanBerger Guys, read the PEP. It is just about emitting a warning when the `encoding` argument is not set. They mention they are aware of the encoding problem but the change is far too big. This PEP should ease the process when someday the actual default utf-8 open encoding PEP will be drafted.

Comment: This is a good example of a very bad decision that was made a long time ago.   Why give the pretense of being cross-platform when things that do not have to be cross-platform are not cross-platform by default.

Comment: The madness will finally be ended in Python 3.15. [PEP 686: Make UTF-8 mode default](https://peps.python.org/pep-0686/) has been accepted.

Comment: The madness will finally be ended with the demise of Windows. `sys.getfilesystemencoding() # 'utf-8'` `locale.getpreferredencoding() # 'cp1252'`

Comment: Got bitten by this and lost a couple hours trying to track this down. I am the only one using a windows laptop on my dev team and the encoding was unspecified in some of the calls to 'open()'. lesson learned is that for code to be cross platform the encoding should be explicitly specified. Wonder if I should switch to developing on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Following the advice [here](https://dev.to/methane/python-use-utf-8-mode-on-windows-212i), the problem can also be solved by setting the environment variable `PYTHONUTF8=1`. This causes `open` to use UTF-8 encoding by default, rather than the platform's default encoding.

Comment: This is called "UTF-8 Mode", which forces Python to ignore local environment locales. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode. As always, it's better to fix the root cause by setting the correct locale, which should lead to a healthier system.