# how to (re)set default file open() encoding for a whole python 3 script?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

Python reads the default file content encoding from the system. *

[This S.O. question demonstrates that behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303919/python-3-0-open-default-encoding)

I'd like to override that globally, in a script level.  I do NOT want to specify it in every call to "open()".

For example, if my Windows has a CP1255 legacy codepage, I'd like to do:

```
magic_set_file_open_encoding('utf8')
data = open('file').read()     # contents assumed utf8
```

---

- Why this is very silly:

  - python3 was "designed for unicode". So why's the backward cowardliness?
  - Windows' system encoding is for LEGACY features, and not a basis for a system of government.
  - scripts' behavior is thus unpredictable and whimsical.

Answer (score 2):

As an improvement to the "less `hacky` way" of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45786397/4233229), the following will allow to only override the encoding and keep the language specification:

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, (locale.getlocale()[0], "utf8"))
# or alternatively:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, f"{locale.getlocale()[0]}.utf8")
```

Comment: thanks. I moved since to Linux, and I can't verify it yet.

Comment: I see - technically you could change it to any other encoding and then try to open non-UTF8 files within a script. But I agree, who would want to do that "globally" :DD

Answer (score 1):

You can override **open** for your file

```
open = functools.partial(open, encoding='utf8')
# replace *open* by a *new open func* with UTF-8 encoding

with open('somefile') as f:
    ...
```

Another less `hacky` way and more global approach could be:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')
```

Comment: The question specifically states: I do NOT want to specify it in every call to "open()"

Comment: @glexey - After the first line at the start of the script it only uses open without parameters... thats what the OP asked for, a **top level** *magic* to do so.

Comment: Sorry, missed the "partial".. But this solution will not work for any real programs, since open('somefile', 'rb') will be broken with this override. What Windows programmers want to have is the way to specify "utf-8" as default encoding for **text** files..

Comment: @glexey - I've added the locale approach as well, since as you suggested only small modules/scripts will benefit from the first approach ...

Comment: Locale setting doesn't seem to work on Windows: "Error: unsupported locale setting".