# How to make Python use UTF8 by default with `open()` on Windows?

Tags: python

I have code which uses `open("file.txt")` on UTF8 encoded text files.
However, this breaks on Windows as it will use `cp1252` by default.

How can I make the code work without changing the code?

I've seen and tried `PYTHONIOENCODING`, `sys.setdefaultencoding` and `chcp 65001` solutions, but none of them make a difference.

Comment: Check this in case it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303919/python-3-0-open-default-encoding

Comment: Unfortunately not. It explains the reason, but there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use encoding key value argument in open() function as:-

```
file_descriptor = open("file.txt", encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: Yes, but I mean ideally _without_ changing the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `open()` builtin and replace it with your own, which uses utf-8 by default:

Create a file `custom_open.py` with the following function:

```
import builtins

def open(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["encoding"] = "utf8"
    return builtins.open(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, you can add `from custom_open import open` to your existing files and the `open()` function will be overriden, effectively opening all your files in UTF-8.  It's true that it involves changing the existing code, but you just need to add one import to the existing files to make it work.

If you're using Python 2, the `builtins` module should be replaced by `__builtin__` instead:

```
import __builtin__

def open(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["encoding"] = "utf8"
    return __builtin__.open(*args, **kwargs)
```