# How to properly save file to avoid UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, string, encoding

I have a big dataset that will throw a `UnicodeDecodeError` when trying to use the dataset.

I have a `big_file_format_x` and want to format it to `big_file_format_y` like so:

```
with open(PATH, "r") as data:
    for index, line in enumerate(data.readlines()):
        // Formatting logic

with open(SAVE_PATH, "w") as new_data:
    new_data.write(formated_data_string)
```

Then im splitting the formatted dataset into 3 datasets:

```
with open(PATH, "rb") as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        // Do splitting logic

with open('train_data.txt', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(train_data)

with open('vali_data.txt', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(vali_data)

with open('test_data.txt', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(test_data)
```

Now when I want to process the datasets I'm getting

```
    kwargs[name] = annotation.from_params(params=subparams, **subextras)
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 274, in from_params
    return subclass.from_params(params=params, **extras)
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/modules/text_field_embedders/basic_text_field_embedder.py", line 136, in from_params
    for name, subparams in token_embedder_params.items()
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/modules/text_field_embedders/basic_text_field_embedder.py", line 136, in <dictcomp>
    for name, subparams in token_embedder_params.items()
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py", line 274, in from_params
    return subclass.from_params(params=params, **extras)
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/modules/token_embedders/embedding.py", line 200, in from_params
    vocab_namespace)
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/modules/token_embedders/embedding.py", line 270, in _read_pretrained_embeddings_file
    vocab, namespace)
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/modules/token_embedders/embedding.py", line 293, in _read_embeddings_from_text_file
    with EmbeddingsTextFile(file_uri) as embeddings_file:
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/modules/token_embedders/embedding.py", line 450, in __init__
    first_line = next(self._handle)     # this moves the iterator forward
  File "/home/public/s1234/.conda/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defining the encoding should solve this:

```
open(PATH, "r", encoding="UTF-8") # replace UTF-8 with the encoding of your file
```

when saving your file you should define the encoding too. Otherwise your environments default encoding is used: [python 3.0 open() default encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303919/python-3-0-open-default-encoding)

Comment: Still throwing the exception :(

Comment: Let's try to isolate the error: does the error occur while reading or writing?

Comment: The actual formatting and splitting of the data works just fine. The dataset is read by a reader in order to train some nlp model. So error occurs when reading that data..

Comment: ok. Lets try some other encodings: Can you check "utf-8-sig" and "cp1252"?

Comment: Thx for helping out Raphael, this is much appreciated! I'm out for a bit, but I will check later. Should I try for the reading or writing of the files? I'm still lacking an understanding of how stuff is when why encoded in python..

Comment: no prob. Try reading first. Isolating the problem is crucial when debugging. Create a small script which does nothing than reading your input file. If this step works you can go on with your processing and finally writing. The encoding defines how text is stored to binary files. Knowing the encoding of your files is crucial. As a rule of the thumb: always specify the encoding.

Comment: Hey, I found out what the problem was. Some other parameter in my model needed some data too. So the encoding problem wasn’t in my dataset but in that other data... I spend 10 hours encoding my file until i saw in the stacktrace that it’s (clearly) saying the embedding is the problem ... sometimes you gotta be stupid, I guess it’s part of the job. Thanks rapha!!

Comment: hey Marcel, haha great. know that only too well :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have a different encoding in that file than utf-8. 0xba is º character in ISO-8869-1 ecoding.

Try

```
data.encode ("utf-8")
```

Comment: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

Comment: You seem to be trying "w" mode now. If you're using 'wb' then, you'll need bytes, if it's 'w' then you'll need str. data.encode("utf-8") is for the write operations under "wb" modes.