# Different Unicode-Handling between Python 3.8.2 and 3.6.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I know there are a lot questions around here about unicode handling, but I could not find an answer to my problem.

I am trying to read this file called words.txt:

```
privatësia
politika e të dhënave
konfidencialiteti
politikat e privatësisë
```

With those two lines:

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
    PRIVACYWORDS = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

This is totally working fine in my Python 3.8.2 Shell. But if I try to run it inside  the container I want to use, which has Python 3.6.9, it throws the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <listcomp>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Since I opened with the `"r"` parameter and not with `"rb"`, the type of the read data should be `<str>` in Python 3 and thus support the Unicode charset.

Comment: You’re not telling Python what encoding to `open` the file with, and the implicit assumption differs between both your environments based on environment variables and/or perhaps differences between versions. You should explicitly open the file in UTF-8 mode.

Comment: I guess the system encoding and therefore also the Python default encoding in the container is ASCII and not UTF-8.

Comment: Different platforms may use different default encodings: "The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getpreferredencoding returns" ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open)) -- see also  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36316351

Comment: Thanks, it worked with `encoding="utf8"` parameter. But now I got the same problem when I want to print the content of PRIVACYWORDS. Do I need to set an encoding for the print function as well?