# v SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3:

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried putting 'r' before my code, as well as changed the code with back slash/ front slash but don't seem to be able to upload my csv file into python. is there a particular reason for this error?

please help me fix this!!

Comment: please, can you show us your complete traceback and your code?

Comment: code 1 - pd.read_csv('C:/Users/payalsachdev/Desktop/cars.csv').                                      code 2 - pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/payalsachdev/Desktop/cars.csv')                                 code 3 - pd.read_csv('C://Users//payalsachdev//Desktop//cars.csv')                             code 4 - pd.read_csv('C:\Users\payalsachdev\Desktop\cars.csv').                                     I tried these 4 not sure why I'm unable to import this.. could there be an issue with the version?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set also the encoding parameter to `'utf-8'`. If the path to file is correct, bellow code should fix the issue:

```
pd.read_csv('C:/Users/payalsachdev/Desktop/cars.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

If this still doesn't work you can go further and ignore malformed data and continue by setting encoding_errors to `'ignore'`:

```
pd.read_csv('C:/Users/payalsachdev/Desktop/cars.csv', encoding='utf-8', encoding_errors='ignore')
```

You can check more details here: [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), and also why 'utf-8' encoding is not always the default one: [python 3 default encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303919/python-3-0-open-default-encoding)