# Preserving Hindi characters in Python string

Tags: python, string, selenium-webdriver, encoding

I am using Selenium to navigate to a webpage that has some Hindi and English characters on it.

I am using `driver.page_source()` to get the HTML of that page. Now this source code contains Hindi strings as well, so when i am writing it to an HTML file it messes it up.

```
file = open('index.html', 'w')
a.write(driver.page_source())
a.close()
```

I have also tried using encoding it to UTF-8 and writing as a binary, but it still doesn't work.

I know I am making some rookie mistake and anyone with a better understanding of this topic will straight away know what is missing.

I want this:

[image]

but instead I am getting this:

[image]

Comment: The screen shot looks like your broken page contains UTF-8 but you are using some legacy 8-bit encoding to inspect it. We can't tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3 ??

Comment: If you are on windows specifiy `open(..., encoding="utf-8")`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36316351/10513287

Comment: Did you specify the encoding when you saved the page?

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to get some HTML from hindi website and save it in a file

this is the hindi website :

[image]

and i tried to get the source code using requests and save it in a file by this code:

```py
import requests

website = requests.get("https://www.aajtak.in/")


file = open("index.html", "wb")
file.write(website.content)
file.close()
```

and this is the result :

[image]

and it worked fine .. hindi is not my language for the if the we site is saying some thing wrong i am sorry about that >>>> i only wrote hindi websites.

i think the wrong this is you have to convert the data into bytes before putting it in the file.

```py
file = open('index.html', 'wb')
file.write(driver.page_source().encode()) # i do not know if the data is encoded or not but make sure to make it encoded before you write it
file.close()
```

Comment: tired this as well, doesn't work

Comment: @Karan Gupta can you please give us the code who gets the HTML from the website and the website it self to try.