# Broken Json file in python when decoding

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.12

I am making a mod manager which opens the mods manifest.json file for name, description, version and dependencies although when its reading the file... i think ill just show you:

MANIFEST FILE:

```
{
    "name": "HookGenPatcher",
    "version_number": "0.0.5",
    "website_url": "https://github.com/harbingerofme/Bepinex.Monomod.HookGenPatcher",
    "description": "Generates MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.HookGen's MMHOOK file during the BepInEx preloader phase.",
    "dependencies": []
}
```

CODE:

```
from json import JSONDecoder
json = JSONDecoder()

PLUGIN_PATH: str = "./mods"

plugins: dict[str: dict[str: str]] = {}

for mod in os.listdir(path = PLUGIN_PATH):
      mod_path: str = f"{PLUGIN_PATH}/{mod}"
      if is_zipfile(filename = mod_path):
            folder_path: str = ".".join(mod_path.split(sep = ".")[:-1])
            os.mkdir(path = folder_path)

            mod_zip = ZipFile(file = mod_path)
            mod_zip.extractall(path = folder_path)
            mod_zip.close()

            os.remove(path = mod_path)

      with open(file = f"{mod_path}/manifest.json", mode = "r") as f:
            x: list[str] = f.read()
            y: list = []

            for line in x.splitlines():
                  y.append(line.strip())

            y = "".join(y)

            print(y)

            mod_json: dict = json.decode(s = y)

      plugins[mod] = mod_json

print(plugins)
```

OUTPUT:

```
ï»¿{"name": "HookGenPatcher","version_number": "0.0.5","website_url": "https://github.com/harbingerofme/Bepinex.Monomod.HookGenPatcher","description": "Generates MonoMod.RuntimeDetour.HookGen's MMHOOK file during the BepInEx preloader phase.","dependencies": []}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\OneDrive\Code\BetterLCMods\main.pyw", line 58, in <module>
    mod_json: dict = json.decode(s = y)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is only to this manifest file and ive tried deleting it and typing it back out (not copy pasting it)

Im guessing its the "ï»¿" at the start of the file but I have no idea why that is there.

Comment: What about `plugins[mod] = json.loads(open(f"{mod_path}/manifest.json").read())`? You dont need to read the JSON linewise.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I could do that but then i get a new error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\OneDrive\Code\BetterLCMods\main.pyw", line 47, in <module>
    plugins[mod] = json.decode(open(f"{mod_path}/manifest.json").read())

  File "E:\Python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "E:\Python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Other than the fact that you don't need to do split into multiple lines and join it back again, if you look at your output it has the following at the start of your file: `ï»¿`, so your file doesn't really seem to be valid JSON.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thats the point i dont know why its there, the manifent file doesnt contain it, because i have deleted the old one and manually typed it back out as said in the question

Comment: @PhaseAmaze Those dubious looking characters may be in the file. You may not be able to "see" them because of the application you're using to visualise the file. Take a hex dump of the file. The way you do that will depend on your platform. On a \*nix type system you could use *od*. It's probably due to the file's encoding. Try opening it with *encoding='utf-8-sig'*

Comment: @CtrlZ Again I have to say those characters are not in the file.

Comment: Print `f"{mod_path}/manifest.json"` and check if you're looking at the correct file, if the file is correct confirm the encoding of the file and get `open` to use the same encoding.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Looking at the correct file and using correct encoding

Comment: @PhaseAmaze Update your question once you've tried opening the file with an explicit encoding such as the one I suggested

Comment: @PhaseAmaze You are not using an explicit encoding. The encoding that will be used will be dependent on your operating system. We don't know what that is

Comment: @CtrlZ open defaults to utf-8

Comment: @PhaseAmaze "_open defaults to utf-8_" not necessarily. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303919/what-encoding-does-open-use-by-default/36316351#36316351

Comment: @PhaseAmaze but the encoding of your file is almost certainly "utf-8-sig"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat and CtrlZ It opens in utf-8. And look at answers I fixed it no thanks to you

Comment: @PhaseAmaze if you look at this [table in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) the BOM for UTF-8 is `ï»¿` which is what you're looking at in the output. Given that `utf-8-sig` adds the BOM at the start of the file CtrlZ is most likely correct in their assumption about that being the encoding of your file.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Best way / Only way is to add this

```
y = "{" + y.split("{", 1)[-1]
```

The whole new file:

```
from json import JSONDecoder
json = JSONDecoder()

PLUGIN_PATH: str = "./mods"

plugins: dict[str: dict[str: str]] = {}

for mod in os.listdir(path = PLUGIN_PATH):
      mod_path: str = f"{PLUGIN_PATH}/{mod}"
      if is_zipfile(filename = mod_path):
            folder_path: str = ".".join(mod_path.split(sep = ".")[:-1])
            os.mkdir(path = folder_path)

            mod_zip = ZipFile(file = mod_path)
            mod_zip.extractall(path = folder_path)
            mod_zip.close()

            os.remove(path = mod_path)

      with open(file = f"{mod_path}/manifest.json", mode = "r") as f:
            x: list[str] = f.read()
            y: list = []

            for line in x.splitlines():
                  y.append(line.strip())

            y: str = "".join(y)

            y = "{" + y.split("{", 1)[-1]

            mod_json: dict = json.decode(s = y)

      plugins[mod] = mod_json

print(plugins)
```

Comment: No. The "best" way is to open the file with the correct encoding then there's no need for all that convoluted nonsense around splitting, joining and splitting again

Comment: @CtrlZ It is the correct encoding and is only way

Comment: It's the "only way" that you've been able to figure out. It's not the right way

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this demonstration of what a utf-8-sig file looks like will help.

```
FILE = "foo.txt"

with open(FILE, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    f.write("hello")

with open(FILE, "rb") as f:
    b = f.read()
    print(len(b))
    print(*map(chr, b[:3]), sep="")
    print(*map(chr, b[3:]), sep="")
```

**Output:**

```
8
ï»¿
hello
```

The code only wrote 5 characters to the file but 8 bytes were generated due to the 3-character BOM used for this encoding

Comment: This does nothing that I am wanting to do

Comment: Why do i need to know what a utf-8-sig is that is noting to opening a json file

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. Try again