# Decoding of bytes object results in unexpected + invalid UTF-8 - how can I avoid this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

The code below (Python 3.6) takes a bytes object that represents the [multiplication sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm) in UTF-8 (`b'\xc3\x97'`), decodes it to a string, and writes the string to a file:

```py
# Byte sequence corresponds to multiplication sign in UTF-8
myBytes = b'\xc3\x97'
# Decode to string 
myString = myBytes.decode('utf-8')

# Write myString to file
with open("myString.txt", "w") as ms_file:
    ms_file.write(myString)
```

This gives me the following result:

Bytes written to *myString.txt* (checked by opening the file in a hex editor): `D7`

The result I expected here was the 2-byte sequence `C3 97`, which is the UTF-8 representation of the multiplication sign. Moreover, `D7` is not even a valid (one byte) UTF-8 sequence (see also [*UTF-8 Codepage Layout*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout)). It *is* the byte value that matches the [*ISO/IEC 8859-1 (Latin)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding though.

So my question is simply how I can ensure that I end up with valid UTF-8 here. Am I overlooking something really obvious, or is this a bug in Python?

Some context: I ran into this issue while writing some code that processes XML files (that use UTF-8), parses the XML to an Element object with lxml, extracts text values of some elements which are subsequently written to another XML file (which also uses UTF-8). Due to this issue I can now end up with XML files that are not well-formed.

I'm using Python 3.6 under Windows 7.

**EDIT**: original question/code contained a function that was supposed to print a hex representation of *myString* to the screen, but as it turns out it was not behaving as expected. Since this made things unnecessarily confusing (also the function was not essential to the question) I removed it from the code.

Comment: What's your `sys.getdefaultencoding()` say? Note that your `strAsHex()` displays unicode codepoints returned by `ord()`.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452317/default-encoding-of-python-3s-open-under-windows-sys-getdefaultencoding-se

Comment: [@Ilja](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%c3%a4) Thanks, my default enoding is `utf-8`. Wasn't 100% sure about the `strAsHex`either, which is why I double-checked the result by writing the string to file (which also gives me one single `D7` byte)

Comment: ["In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to get the current locale encoding."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), also mentioned in the linked Q/A. Did not remember this myself either, so thank you for this reminder. Easiest way out is to pass `encoding='utf-8'` explicitly to `open()`.

Comment: [@Ilja](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%c3%a4) Brilliant, adding the `encoding='utf-8'` did the trick for me (also works in my full XML processing application). Thank you so much for suggesting this, this was really doing my head in!